# jQuery hiding tab selectors

Tags: jquery, tabs

Does anyone know how I can go about hiding the tab selectors for the jQuery tab control?

I'm trying to do a wizard setup type thing by having multiple views that are hidden but only show up when I want them to.

Any ideas? Something else other than tabs i could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".nextButton").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide().next().show();
  });
  $(".prevButton").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide().prev().show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js">
</script>


<div>
  Tab One<br/>
  <input type="button" class="nextButton" value="next" />
</div>
<div style="display:none;">
  Tab Two<br/>
  <input type="button" class="prevButton" value="prev" />
  <input type="button" class="nextButton" value="next" />
</div>
<div style="display:none;">
  Tab Three<br/>
  <input type="button" class="prevButton" value="prev" />
</div>
```

Comment: I had no idea I could do that. Makes sense. I feel stupid! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just create divs on top of each other and show/hide them using show() and hide(). There is no need for tabs, if you only want to switch views programatically. It is as simple as that

Html:

```
<div class="view" id="view1">
</div>
<div class="view" id="view2">
</div>
<div class="view" id="view2">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function selectView(i) {
    $(".view").hide();
    $("#view" + 1).show();
}
```

or if you don't want to use ids:

```
function selectView(i) {
    $(".view").hide();
    $(".view :eq(" + 1 + ")").show();
}
```